# In Mac, how to create a button in dock to launch screen saver immediately?

Tags: macos, mac, screensaver

In Mac, how to create a button in dock to launch screen saver immediately?  I.e. use the screen saver as an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drag `/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/` to the Dock.

Comment: When I click it, it runs screen saver for about 3 seconds, and then quickly quits.  Why?

Comment: I don't know. It stays open for me. You could also try saving `do shell script "open -a ScreenSaverEngine"` as an application in AppleScript Editor and drag it to the Dock.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this appears to be to activate *Hot Corners* for the screensaver as shown [here](https://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#quickscreensaver)

The Hot corner can be selected from **System preference > Desktop&ScreenSaver > ScreenSaver > Hot Corners**. This will activate screensaver when you move your mouse into that corner.

Alternatively if what you want to do is put the display to sleep, you can do what Seph suggests [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3081180?start=0&tstart=0). Pressing Control-Shift-Eject will put your display to sleep.

The latter link also has some other methods involving automator and etc.

Comment: Why you answer questions I don't ask.  I know these. But those aren't what i want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Automator. Open Automator and create a new application. From the list of available actions select startScreenSaver. Drag this to the right side onto the editor. Save the application as 'startScreenSaver' under documents. Now quit Automator and in finder go to Documents under your username. Drag and drop 'startScreenSaver' to your dock.

Thats it. When you want screen saver just click this button. I used this solution because hot corners wasn't an option for me, but if hot corner is an option, that would be the best way to do this.